# Laplacian quadratic form and effective resistance

Tags: matrices, graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory, graph-laplacian

Consider a graph $G=(V,E)$ with positive edge weights. For simplicity, in my question, you can also assume unweighted graph. I am trying to show that the Laplacian quadratic form of the graph consisting of the $V$ nodes with only one edge $\{ u, v \} \in E$ in it is at most that of the whole graph $G$ times the effective resistance of edge $\{u,v\} \in G$, i.e.,

$$ x^T L_{u,v} x \leq R_{u,v}[G] x^T L_G x, \text{ for any vector } x \in  \mathbb{R}^{n \times 1} $$

and this was claimed that it is known on page 6 of [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1145/2948062), before the corollary. Any hint would be appreciated.